# Unit testing with Spock fails when using use(TimeCategory)

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 in my project, and I'm trying to write a unit test case using Spock. The method I'm trying to unit test uses `use(TimeCategory)`. The test case was running for too long, and on debug I found that it's not moving past the point in code where I had `use(TimeCategory)`. Please find below the method and the test case I have written for it:

```
def getEstimatedSl(val) {

        // some code
        calculateSl()
        // some code
    }

def calculateSl() {
    use(TimeCategory) {
            interval = 10 
            startDate = //some date value// 
            endDate = //some date value// 
        } 

        while (endDate.compareTo(startDate) >= 0) { 
            use(TimeCategory) { 
                startDate += interval 
            } 
        }
}

void "test getEstimatedSl success"() {
        when:
        def dto = service.getEstimatedSl('ABCDEFGH')

        then:
        dto.slots ==  /*dto value that I get*/
        dto.count == 4
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to want to add what the error is that you're seeing, or why you think the values you're seeing are wrong.  Also, it looks like you've culled the code too much, as it's difficult to see how you're using "val" etc.

Comment: Hi Bill, I'm not seeing any error at all. The test case just runs for too long until I go and stop it. When I debugged I found that it's not moving past the line where I have `use(TimeCategory)`. I'm using `val` to pass to a dynamic finder in the code to get a domain class object.

Comment: Well, then I suggest showing what code is inside the use(TimeCategory) block.  If it's large, consider cutting out some code, making sure the test still locks, and showing that instead.

Comment: There was a large piece of code inside `use(TimeCategory)`, so I broke it down and repeated `use(TimeCategory)` only where I needed it. Please find the changed code below:

Comment: @tim_yates : I have edited my post with the code.

Comment: @Bill : I debugged some more, and it seems like the code inside `use(TimeCategory)` is not getting executed. for instance, the start time is not getting incremented in the while loop, making it run infinitely. Can you suggest a way to write test cases so `use(TimeCategory)` would work? I have explored quite a few options, and am unable to find an alternative to `TimeCategory` for my implementation.

Comment: Isn't it a problem of scopes?

Comment: @Opal : Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I mean `use(TimeCategory)` nesting. Could you please a runnable groovy script (with dependencies) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm late in posting my answer, but it turned out there was nothing wrong with the code in my service. I had not set the interval (on line 10) in my test case, hence my while was going in an infinite loop. 
Thanks for the help anyway, folks!